# Javascript IE7/IE8 Discrepancy

Tags: javascript

When I use `document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked == true` in IE8 it does not work but works in IE7, any solutions please?

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
function swap(){ 
        if(document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked == true ){  
           document.getElementById('captionrow1').style.display = "none";
           document.getElementById('captionrow2').style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById('show').style.display = "inline";

                        if (location.href.indexOf("CheckBox1=1") == -1)
                                location.href = "employees_commends1a.asp?CheckBox1=1";
         } 
   if(document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked == false ){  
            document.getElementById('captionrow1').style.display = "inline";
           document.getElementById('captionrow2').style.display = "none";
           document.getElementById('show').style.display = "none";
      } 
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Side note: [the `language` attribute is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/script)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the checkbox has a unique ID Also your code changes the location = unloads the page - I am sure that is what makes your code not work.

I suggest this instead:

```
window.onload=function() {
  var chk = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
  chk.checked=location.href.indexOf("CheckBox1=1") != -1
  chk.onclick=function() { 
    location = "employees_commends1a.asp?"+(this.checked?"CheckBox1=1":"CheckBox1=0");
  }
  swap();
}

function swap(){ 
  var checked = document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked;
  document.getElementById('captionrow1').style.display = (checked)?"none":"inline";
  document.getElementById('captionrow2').style.display = (checked)?"inline":"none";
  document.getElementById('show').style.display = (checked)?"inline":"none";
}

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
```